# Odoo module structure: what is the "controllers" directory and how th is used in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

What is the "controllers" directory and how it used in odoo

[image]

Comment: The directory contains the web controllers to handle http requests. You can start by checking the docs: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/http.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Odoo, 'Controllers' are used to configure the frontend modules. These frontend modules come integrated with the backend modules. For example, if one needs to bring the sales order details to the website, he can't use the functionality of 'Models' in Odoo.